# fs-extra copy file outputs blank file

Tags: node.js, fs, fs-extra

When I run the following code a blank file gets created with the correct name. I clearly dont want a blank file.

I know the path is correct because when i make it purposely incorrect it fails (obviously)

```
const path = require('path');
const fse = require('fs-extra');
const OUTPUT_PATH   = 'js/libs/';
const _NODE_MODULES   = 'node_modules/';
const filePath        = `${_NODE_MODULES}tooltipster/dist/js/tooltipster.bundle.min.js`;

fse.copy(path.join(__dirname, filePath), path.join(__dirname, `${OUTPUT_PATH}/something.js`), err => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    process.exit(1)
  }
  console.log('Copy complete');
  process.exit(0);
})
```

Output of this is
`Copy Complete` 
But the file is blank as I previously stated. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified Your code and checked on my PC.

So result: http://joxi.ru/ZrJEEJh1KXw1Aj[image: here]

Checkout this code:

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs-extra');

let sourceFile = path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'tooltipster/dist/js/tooltipster.bundle.min.js');
let destinationFile = path.join(__dirname, 'js/libs', 'something.js');

fs.copy(sourceFile, destinationFile, err => {
  if (err) {
    return console.error(err);
  }

  console.log('Copy complete');
});
```

if it fail again so, be sure that there is no issue with code.

check Your filesystem maybe there is some open file limits, permission problems or no free space.

also I can guess that the source file is empty, so do:

```
cat node_modules/tooltipster/dist/js/tooltipster.bundle.min.js
```

Comment: It was a file permission issue. Thanks @num8er for the help

Answer (score 0):

Your call to process.exit interfered/aborted before it could finish.  Don't need to call process.exit.  It will exit when everything is done.

Comment: Yeah, i was being explicit as that is only ever ran as a standalone module